# Hookes law Bungee jumping question

Tags: mathematical-physics

ive seen a few forums with answers for these but im finding a fair few different results and im getting confused. Perhaps someone here can help:

A bungee rope is specially designed and its modulus of elasticity is such that the rope is stretched to twice its natural length by a person of 75kg hanging at rest from the free end.

for a person of m kg, calculate the depth to which the person would fall if attached to a rope of the type described above. Assume the jumper is a particle so that their height can be ignored.

Comment: Please edit it and make it more readable.

Comment: If it helps any, this is a link to the same question answered by other people, however i am just unsure how he got to his depth equation. any help would be appreciated! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396485/dynamics-bungee-jumping-grade-12-maths-c/2898229?noredirect=1#comment5986168_2898229

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use conservation of energy.  Neglecting friction, when the jumper reaches the lowest depth, the potential energy lost in the fall is equal to the potential energy from stretching of the rope.